# Вывод powershell в файл

Tags: git, powershell, fetch, git-merge

Есть у меня папка, в которую я клонирую интересные мне git-репозитории. В папке есть .bat-файл со следующим содержимым:

```
@ECHO off

for /d %%B in (%cd%\*) do (
powershell.exe "ECHO %%B | tee -FilePath tag.txt -Append"
cd %%B
git status
git stash
powershell.exe "git fetch | tee -FilePath ../tag.txt -Append"
powershell.exe "git merge | tee -FilePath ../tag.txt -Append"
cd ../)

@pause
@exit
```

Я пытаюсь сохранить в файл информацию о git pull, который, как известно, состоит из fetch и merge. При этом, merge в файл сохраняется, но у него нет информации о новый тегах, у fetch такая информация есть, но он в файл не сохраняется. Подскажите, в чём дело?

Comment: Попробуйте вывод стандартного потока ошибок тоже перенаправлять куда-нибудь, хотя я скорее предположу, что git проверяет терминал или конвейер, и поэтому доп. информацию в последний и не выводит.

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли перенаправить стандартный вывод ошибок. Например: `merge 2>&1`.